# How to get Data & Control Dependency Slice using Frama-c

Tags: c, slice, frama-c, program-slicing

I was trying to do two things

1. Get a dynamic backward slice based on a criteria.
2. Map the slices statements back to the actual source code.

Problem 1: The slice returned by Frama-C doesn't return the exact statements that were relevant for the criteria - mainly the `if` and `else` statements.

Problem 2: How do I map the slicing statements back to the source code? The program gets changed when slicing (for example : `int a=9` becomes 2 statements in sliced code `int a;` and `a = 9;`.) I am ok with the slice but what is the information I can use to map these back to the statements in the source code.

---

This is the source code.

```
void main(){
   int ip1 = 9;
   int ip2 = 3;
   int option = 1;
   int result = math(option,ip1,ip2);    
   //@ slice pragma expr ((option == 1) || !(result == (ip1+ip2)));    
 }   

int math(int option, int a, int b){
   int answer = 0;
   if (option == 1){   
     answer = a+b;
   }else{   
     if (option == 2) {   
       answer = a-b;   
     }else { // a ^ b   
       for(int i=0 ;i<b; i++){   
           answer=answer*a;   
       }   
     }
   }
   return answer;
   }
```

---

I use the following command to get the slice.

```
frama-c t.c -slicing-level 3 -slice-pragma main -slice-print
```

The slice I get from frama-c is :

```
void main(void)
{
  int ip1;
  int ip2;
  int option;
  int result;
  ip1 = 9;
  ip2 = 3;
  option = 1;
  result = math_slice_1(ip1,ip2);
  /*@ slice pragma expr option≡1∨!(result≡ip1+ip2); */ ;
  return;
}

int math_slice_1(int a, int b)
{
  int answer;
  answer = a + b;
      return answer;
}
```

Problem 1: 
I dont get the `if` and `else` conditions in the slice. What should I do to get them?

I expected the following slice:

```
    int math_slice_1(int a, int b)    
    {
      int answer;
       if (option == 1){ 
          answer = a + b; 
       }
      return answer;
    }
```

Problem 2:
Source code has : `int ip1 = 9;`

But the sliced code has :

```
 int ip1;
 ip1 = 9;
```

How to map these 2 sliced statements back to the source code statement.

Comment: For Problem 2, the source program is “normalized” so that the thousands of way to express the same thing in C are reduced to a minimal number of constructs. However, programmatically you should still be able to obtain the information that the assignment `ip1 = 9;` originates from line 2 in file t.c, if this is the sort of mapping back to the source code statement you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Problem 1, the test is sliced out because it is always true since `option` is set to 1 in the main function. If you want to keep the test, you have to make `option` an entry (either external global variable or a parameter of `main` for instance), but then, there will be nothing to slice in the `math` function... The slicing tries to keep only what is strictly necessary, and the test is not in your case.